in the sentence, "How much will we have left over once we've paid all the suppliers" does 'left over' function as a verb or an adjective?
in the sentence

How much will we have left over once we've paid all the suppliers

I thought 'left over' functions as a verb, together with 'we have,' forming the clause 'we will have left over.'
Then I was told it functions as an adjective, but I can't imagine which word(s) it describes. Any clues would be greatly appreciated.

Left is an adjective here and means remaining,  as explained in Collins Dictionary sense B1:

adjective [verb-link ADJECTIVE]
If there is a certain amount of something left, or if you have a certain amount of it left, it remains when the rest has gone or been used.


He's got plenty of money left.

left
The OP’s example

How much will we have left over once we've paid all the suppliers?

means the same as this without over:
How much will we have left  once we've paid all the suppliers?
The example quoted by the OP was  from Cambridge Dictionary's definition for be left over; the phrasal verb mentioned there refers to be left over.
Edit to Answer the OP’s Further Query
The noun modified is money:
How much [money] will we have left once ...?
This rephrase may be clearer:
How much [money left] will we have once ...?

thank you. would you please explain which word(s) the adjective 'left' describes?

@singularli, I have added my reply to this in my answer.

Note that to be left [over] is inherently passive, so although you can say $10 remains as well as $10 is remaining, you can only say $10 is left [over].

Thanks, @FumbleFingers.   Yes, it's usually in the past participle form.  The form $10 leaves would mean the opposite ...

as in the money leaving us, leaving our wallets.

I. Left over vs leftover vs leftovers.
OP has asked:

How much will we have left over once we've paid all the suppliers?
Then I was told it functions as an adjective, but I can't imagine which word(s) it describes.

Your earlier information that "left over" is a verbal phrase  is correct.
It cannot function as an adjective because the adjective form is a single word "leftover".
be left over = verbal phrase
leftover= adjective
leftover(s) = noun used for food only.
Please refer to the website's information and dictionary definitions given below.
II. Explanation of left over and leftover
Ref. writersdigest.com

Not sure the best trick to use, but the first part might just be to remember that leftovers is the noun form,
leftover is the adjective form, and left over is the phrase that's used after.
So the leftover food can be called leftovers if it's the food that is left over after a meal..
https://www.writersdigest.com/write-better-fiction/left-over-vs-leftover-vs-leftovers-grammar-rules#:~:text=Not%20sure%20the%20best%20trick,left%20over%20after%20a%20meal.

This sentence appears to be a conversation between a manager and an accountant, as it deals with financial planning, budgeting, and cash flow management.
Ref. Collins dictionary

left over.
phrase B2.
If there is a certain amount of something left over, or if you have it left over, it remains when the rest has gone or been used.
So much income is devoted to monthly mortgage payments that nothing is left over.
leftover.
adjective [ADJECTIVE noun].
You use leftover to describe an amount of something that remains after the rest of it has been used or eaten.
...leftover pieces of wallpaper.
Leftover chicken makes a wonderful salad.

III. Explanation of OP's sentence..
Let's consider OP's sentence:

How much will we have left over once we've paid all the suppliers?

This sentence appears to be a conversation between a manager and an accountant, as it deals with financial planning, budgeting, and cash flow management.
"Will have left over" is  the future perfect form of the verb phrase "have left over".
We must rephrase the sentence if we want to use "leftover" (a single word) as an adjective in the same sentence:
"How much leftover amount will we have once we've paid all the suppliers?".
In this case, "leftover" is an adjective modifying the noun "amount" or "money", describing the amount or money that remains.
So, to summarise, "leftover" (one word) can be used as an adjective, whereas "left over" (two words) is a phrasal verb.

I would understand it to be similar to remaining not only in meaning but in how it is formed from the participle of a verb, the present participle of remain and the past participle of leave.

We will have some money remaining after the suppliers are paid.
We will have some money left over after the suppliers are paid.

Consider:

Paying the suppliers and the contractors everything they're owed will leave us with no money for that golden toilet you have had your eye on.  There will be no money left over.  It would leave us a zero balance.

